# Not in scope: data constructor simple code

Tags: haskell

My first program in haskell doesn't compile:

```
RemoveOdd nums =
    if null nums
    then []
    else 
        if mod (head nums) 2 == 0
        then (head nums) : (RemoveOdd (tail nums))
        else RemoveOdd (tail nums)

main=RemoveOdd [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

my.hs:1:1: Not in scope: data constructor `RemoveOdd'

my.hs:6:37: Not in scope: data constructor `RemoveOdd'

my.hs:7:22: Not in scope: data constructor `RemoveOdd'

my.hs:9:6: Not in scope: data constructor `RemoveOdd'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions may not start with an uppercase letter. Only types, type constructors, classes, modules or data constructors may start with an uppercase letter:

```
removeOdd nums =
    if null nums
    then []
    else 
        if mod (head nums) 2 == 0
        then (head nums) : (removeOdd (tail nums))
        else removeOdd (tail nums)

main = removeOdd [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

That being said, you should probably have a look at pattern matching, and `filter`, since `removeOdd = filter even`.